# What is the way to implement Observable other than Control.Lens.Setter in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, getter-setter, setter

[Control.Lens.Setter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.7.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html) is remarkable to use  Observable feature in Haskell. ( function/functor to be triggered when the value in the dataset is updated.  )

However, considering the lens is not included in the standard environment, and then required to extra installation, without the lens, when I want to use just a primitive setter feature such as with a field label:

```
data Foo = Foo {val :: Int}
```

How to do this?

Does ST Monad fit this purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of [lets-lens](https://github.com/data61/lets-lens)? you can build your own lens in multiple ways.

Comment: The word "function" is not generally interchangeable with the word "functor". They are different things.

Comment: A Setter is not a function or a functor that is triggered "when the value in the dataset is updated". A Setter is not at all the same thing as an Observable.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Depends on a programming language. A couple of languages call it as a setter, so you cannot deny it.

Comment: @KenOKABE This is a question about Haskell and you specifically referred to Control.Lens.Setter. What other languages may call a “setter” is irrelevant to your question as asked.

Answer (score 3):

It's not very clear what you're looking for here, but if you just want to update a record field, you can use the Haskell record update syntax:

```
x = Foo { val = 5 }
y = x { val = 42 }
```

This works for any record, with any number of fields, and you don't need to list all the fields, only the ones you'd like to update, for example:

```
data D = D { a :: String, b :: Int }

x = D { a = "foo", b = 42 }
y = x { a = "bar" }  -- now y = D { a = "bar", b = 42 }
z = x { b = 43 }  -- now z = D { a = "foo", b = 43 }
```

Keep in mind that this doesn't actually *update* ("change", "mutate") the values in memory, but rather creates *copies* of the records with all the fields equal to those of the original record, except the updated fields. Lenses work the same way, and in fact everything in Haskell does, since Haskell doesn't allow mutation at all.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yeah, I know this in fact. Generally speaking, the term "setter" is a function/functor to be triggered when the value in the dataset is updated. ie) Observable. I also understand the mutation issue. The fact is ST Monad in Haskell behaves as if it mutates, and perhaps it's more efficient. That is why I refered it in my Question.

Comment: A function to be triggered when a value is updated is generally called a "listener", not "setter".

Comment: @KenOKABE That is not what anyone else in this community means when they say the word 'setter'.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you're a bit confused between a few concepts; specifically, setter vs observable.

- I don't know much about them, but an **observable** does seem to be, as you described, a way to run a function every time a value is changed. This concept does not exist in Haskell; I'm sure you could make it somehow, but it wouldn't be very useful, since (almost) every Haskell value is immutable.
- By contrast, a **setter** is just a function which changes part of a value, the same as with Java getters and setters. The only slight complication is that in Haskell, all values are immutable (as I mentioned above), so instead of changing the value, a setter copies the value across but with the thing set. For instance, if you have a setter `setName` (for a record), and you invoke it with something like `setName "foo" oldRecord`, this will keep `oldRecord` as is, but return a new record with the name set to `"foo"`. As you already know, there are other, more complex, implementations of setters, such as lenses.
- You also mention **ST**. This is a more advanced concept; it's basically used when you *have* to use some sort of mutable variable locally but still retain purity (which is not very often).

Now to answer your other question: How do I use setters without lenses? Well, if you have a record like `data Foo = Foo {val :: Int, val2 :: String}` (your example + an extra field), and you have an old record - let's say `oldRecord = Foo { val = 1, val2 = "test" }`, Haskell has special setter syntax: doing `oldRecord { val = 2 }` will give a **new** record with `val` set to `2` - that is, it will give `Foo { val = 2, val2 = "test" }`. Obviously this syntax is a bit clumsy though for nested records, which is the reason lenses were invented.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Well, "immutability" in Haskell is just main="here". "main" connects RealWorld that is mutable, and STMonad's `runST` imports the mutable RealWolrd, that essentially same as IO monad in design.

Comment: @KenOKABE I think you've slightly misunderstood what I'm trying to say. By 'immutability' I mean that once you've created a value such as `Foo { val=1, val2="test" }`, you can't then change `val` to `2` without creating a new object. By contrast, in languages such as Java or C#, if you have an object `myFoo` of class `Foo`, with `myFoo.val = 1` and `myFoo.val2 = "test`, you can then simply change `myFoo.val = 2` without creating a new `Foo` object.

Comment: I think I did not misunderstand. Here's my confirmation to your thought. Do you agree to the idea `unsafePerformIO` is a mutable act or not.  Plus, I know the thing about "immutability" that you repeatedly mention in answer and comment. What I'm asking here is your deep understanding of immutability.

Comment: @KenOKABE 'Do you agree to the idea `unsafePerformIO` is a mutable act or not.' I don't quite know what you mean by a 'mutable act' here. However, this is my understanding of mutability and `unsafePerformIO`: if you have an `IO` action which mutates an `IORef` or similar, then `unsafePerformIO` will convert it into a 'pure' computation (although it isn't really) which has the side-effect of modifying a value. However, irregardless of whether you're inside `IO` or not, you can **never** mutate a value which isn't in an `IORef`, `STRef` or similar mutable reference type.

Comment: @dfeuer I wrote a book about functional programming published by one of the major publishers in Japan, so I know what I'm talking about. Your comment is not polite indeed. What I found very "unuseful" is that some people comments "it's unuseful" when one discuss some concept. "Think" or "not think" by someone should absolutely not be your concern, especially in programming topic..

Comment: I think the major problem of your opinion is that it's always Gray colored. " (although it isn't really) which has the side-effect of modifying a value." this is so-called mutable.  "since (almost) every Haskell value is immutable." "This concept does not exist in Haskell; I'm sure you could make it somehow, but it wouldn't be very useful" <-Do you know there's a concept of Functional Reactive Programming in Haskell?? You are saying it does not exist, or not useful. Perhaps you are not aware of it.

Comment: @KenOKABE I think we're actually saying the same thing, but just having a bit of trouble communicating. My view is as follows: all _values_ in Haskell are immutable; that is, you can't reassign a value which has already been assigned. However, a value may 'point' to another value which _is_ mutable. For instance, an `IORef` _value_ is immutable, but may 'point' to another value stored in memory which may be mutated via the `readIORef` and `writeIORef` functions. (Comment continued in next comment.)

Comment: @KenOKABE FRP is similar: the whole point is that in FRP time-varying values are treated as immutable 'behaviours', with the time variation not able to be observed within the program. (By the way, your book sounds interesting; do you have a link I can look at?)